# Multiple actions were found on controller after upgrading to mvc4 rc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have been using mvc webapi beta and are trying to upgrade to the rc.

We have the following routes (only constraint is to verify that {id} is an integer):

```
"Api Verb with SubAction"   api/{controller}/{id}/{action}
"Api Verb with Id"          api/{controller}/{id}
"Api Verb without Id"       api/{controller}
"Api Action with Id"        api/{controller}/{action}/{id}
"Api Action without Id"     api/{controller}/{action}
```

And the following controller actions

```
public IList<PaymentMethodViewModel> GetList()
{}

public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
{}

[ActionName("Details")]
public IList<RecurrenceModel> GetDetails(Guid id)
{}
```

api/mycontroller, api/mycontroller/1, api/mycontroller/1/details all returned correctly in the beta.  However, after upgrading to MVC4 RC api/mycontroller/1, api/mycontroller/1/details return "Multiple actions were found that match the request:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I had similar problems and failed to find a proper reason. It is obviously due to the changes to the routing implementation but the code for it is quite hefty and I didn't have the time to go over it yet.

Given that it will continue to evolve at this pace, it may be best to depend on built-in routing mechanism only for default `{controller}/{id}` style of routing and [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) for anything else.